# Concatenate in SQL Server 2008 R2 failing when the monthid is 2 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, concatenation

I have a table like and server is SQL Server 2008 R2 where we cannot use `concat` function

```
YearID  |   MonthId     
--------+----------
2017    |    1  
2014    |    5  
2014    |   10  
2016    |   12
```

I want to have the output as

```
201701   
201405   
201410   
201612
```

What I tried so far

```
select 
    cast(YearId as varchar(50)) + '0' + cast(MonthId as varchar(50)) 
from 
    TEST
```

I am getting the output as

```
201701     
201405   
2014010   
2016012
```

When the `monthID` is 2 digits, it is failing.

How to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could verify the length of `MonthId` by `LEN()` function with simple `case` expression

```
SELECT CAST(YearID AS VARCHAR(8))+CASE
                                        WHEN LEN(CAST(MonthId AS VARCHAR(8))) = 2
                                        THEN CAST(MonthId AS VARCHAR(8))
                                        ELSE '0'+CAST(MonthId AS VARCHAR(8))
                                    END
FROM <table_name>;
```

Result :

```
201701
201405
201410
201612
```

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT CAST(YearID * 100 + MonthID AS VARCHAR(6))
FROM mytable
```

Note, we are using only one cast operation here and arithmetic operations only. No additional checks and functions are used.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is (imho):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YearID) + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MOnthId), 2)
FROM TEST;
```

[test here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0fa9/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE (YearID INT ,MOnthId INT)
INSERT INTO @Tmp
SELECT 2017 ,1   UNION ALL
SELECT 2014 ,5   UNION ALL 
SELECT 2014 ,10  UNION ALL
SELECT 2016 ,12

SELECT * FROM @Tmp

SELECT 
CASE WHEN LEN(MOnthId)>1 THEN CAST(YearId AS VARCHAR(50)) + CAST(MonthId AS VARCHAR(50)) 
     ELSE CAST(YearId AS VARCHAR(50)) + '0' + CAST(MonthId AS VARCHAR(50))END
 FROM @Tmp

Results :
201701
201405
201410
201612
```